In table, I want the height of tds to be based on tallest td's height of the table using hml and css
I am using weasyprint package for template in django, I want one functionality that height should be same for all td's which is based on the tallest height td of the table. How can I manage this using html and css only?
I am using this type of css but didn't find a solution
(https://stackoverflow.com)
.equal-row-height-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.equal-row-height-table td,
.equal-row-height-table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.equal-row-height-table tr {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

.equal-row-height-table td:first-child {
  width: 30px;
}

.equal-row-height-table td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50%;
}

.equal-row-height-table td:nth-child(n+3) {
  width: 10%;
  text-align: right;
}

.equal-row-height-table .product-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.equal-row-height-table .product-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.equal-row-height-table .product-details {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 0.9em;
} 


html is missing here to reproduce your issue. You can use the snippet [<>] button to provide a code sample that shows your issue with your attempts. ;)

Also equal height rows requires JS in a table, I believe. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtml-table%5D+table+equal+height+rows
